# How to mirror multiple sources to a single destination?

Tags: windows-7, backup, nas, mirroring

I have multiple 2-3TB drives inside and connected to my working PC. The data I want to backup on each system lies in the folder "digitalized" (photos, time-lapse, etc).

I have a NAS (PC with 8 drives in a JBOD array) with 9TB free.

I would like to mirror each of my source drives to my backup PC:

```
d:\digitalized -> b:\
e:\digitalized -> b:\
f:\digitalized -> b:\
g:\digitalized -> b:\
h:\digitalized -> b:\
```

I manually copied of all source drives to the NAS (which took about 4 days). [image: Here is a WinDirStat screenshot.] (Full-size here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAg9z.jpg - 2 million baby jpegs, eeeeeh!)

Now, one month later, a lot has been deleted, edited and added on the source drives so I need to synchronize everything.

I also have a kazillion tiny useless catalog preview files (from Lightroom) which I would like to ignore. Here is what I have come up with so far:

> robocopy X:\DiGiTaLiZeD B:\ *.* /zb /e /purge /eta /xd *.lrdata /xf *.lrprev

Replace 'X' with each drive letter and repeat. Put into a batch file which runs whenever NAS is pingable.

### Problem:

Each time robocopy runs, /purge sees that 75% of the files located on dest do NOT exist on source (D:) because that data is from E:, F:, etc., so it begins to delete everything else! BAD ROBOCOPY BAD! :(

Any clever ideas? It doesn't have to involve robocopy but I thought it would be the simplest since it's included with Windows.

Comment: When I want to mirror files from one location to another, I use robocopy with the /MIR switch.  You can probably exclude your tiny annoying files by simply using the same /xd and /xf switches you already use.
Generally: robocopy source destination /MIR /R:1 /W:1

Comment: Same problem. BTW /mir is the same as /e + /purge which is what I was doing.

Comment: On your B:\ drive, can you instead use B:\FromD\, B:\FromE\ etc?  Do all the files NEED to be located together in a single destination?

Comment: Actually no, but that's a really good point which would probably solve my entire problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you'd like, I can post that as the answer?

Comment: Sure. Admittedly it isn't my ideal solution, but the alternative is to create a catalog of all sources before synchronizing, which will probably require some 3rd party software (which is worse;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of copying your many source drives to the root directory of B:\, create sub directories (B:\FromD\, B:\FromE\ etc) and use robocopy to mirror each source to the sub directories on the B: drive.

Comment: Which would mean `B:\FromD\images`, `B:\FromE\images`, `B:\FromF\images`, `B:\FromG\images`, `B:\FromH\images`, `B:\FromD\videos`, `B:\FromE\videos`, `B:\FromF\videos`, `B:\FromG\videos` … `B:\FromD\misc`, `B:\FromE\misc`, `B:\FromF\misc` … `B:\FromD\panoramas`, `B:\FromE\panoramas` and so on. This causes all of the store to become extremely fragmented with related files scattered everywhere. Besides having a backup, the whole point to putting them all in one location is so that they can be organized, sorted, de-duped, and cataloged which this method prevents.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but since my own intention is `solely` to make a backup of my drives, this solution fits. It also has the advantage that if I lose a drive, I can easily find out which files (and directories) were affected.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the /purge operation. Its checking each source each time. Run either a separate copy pass with the purge option or simply delete the files with another *.* line.